# Drawing a Pyraminx with triangles

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm trying to code a Pyraminx which is a tetrahedon composed with multiples triangles.
The way I do it must not be very accurate. Here is my code, also available at https://codepen.io/jeffprod/pen/XWbBZLN .

The problem is that i'im writing the `facesVectors` coordinates handly. It seems ok for the yellow and blue side. But it is going difficult to set the position of red and green triangles.

Is there a simple way to do ?

```js
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(60, innerWidth / innerHeight, 1, 100);
camera.position.set(-2, 1, 3);
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(innerWidth, innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

let controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);

// one triangle equilateral
const sideLength = 1
const x = 0
const y = 0
const geometry = new THREE.Geometry()
geometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(x, (Math.sqrt(3) / 2 * sideLength) - (sideLength / 2), 0))
geometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(x - (sideLength / 2), y - (sideLength / 2), 0))
geometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(x + (sideLength / 2), y - (sideLength / 2), 0))
geometry.faces.push(new THREE.Face3(0, 1, 2))

const facesColors = [
  0xFFFF00, // yellow
  0xFF0000, // red
  0x0000FF, // blue
  0x008000 // green
]

// 36 triangles composing the pyraminx
// numbers are indexes of facesColors 
const pos = [
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3
]

// vectors of each triangle composing the tetrahedron
const facesVectors = [
  [0, 0, -1.5],
  [-0.52, 0, -0.6],
  [0, 0, -0.48],
  [0.52, 0, -0.6],
  [-1.04, 0, 0.3],
  [-0.52, 0, 0.42],
  [0, 0, 0.3],
  [0.52, 0, 0.42],
  [1.04, 0, 0.3],
  [-1.2, -0.16, 0.2],
  [-1.04, -0.45, 0.55],
  [-0.52, -0.34, 0.62],
  [0, -0.45, 0.55],
  [0.52, -0.34, 0.62],
  [1.04, -0.45, 0.55],
  [1.2, -0.16, 0.15],
  [-0.6, -0.16, -0.7],
  [-0.9, -0.3, -0.1],
  [-0.5, -0.5, -0.5]
]

for (let i = 0; i < facesVectors.length; i++) {
  material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: facesColors[pos[i]] })
  face = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material)
  face.position.set(facesVectors[i][0], facesVectors[i][1], facesVectors[i][2])
  // some rotations
  if ([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8].includes(i)) {
    face.rotation.x = -(Math.PI / 2)
  }
  if ([2, 5, 7, 10, 12, 14].includes(i)) { // 180
    face.rotation.z = Math.PI
  }
  if ([9, 16, 17, 18, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29].includes(i)) {
    if (i === 17) {
      face.rotation.x = -(1 * Math.PI) / 6
      face.rotation.y = -(2 * Math.PI) / 3
      face.rotation.z = -(1 * Math.PI) / 6
    } else {
      face.rotation.x = -Math.PI / 6
      face.rotation.y = -2 * Math.PI / 3
      face.rotation.z = Math.PI / 6
    }
  }
  if ([15, 22, 23, 24, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35].includes(i)) {
    face.rotation.x = -Math.PI / 6
    face.rotation.y = 2 * Math.PI / 3
    face.rotation.z = -Math.PI / 6
  } else if ([10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 19, 20, 21, 30].includes(i)) {
    face.rotation.x = Math.PI / 6
  }
  scene.add(face)
}

renderer.setAnimationLoop(() => {
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://threejs.org/build/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 4 corner points of a [Tetrahedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetrahedron) are:

```js
let s_8_9 = Math.sqrt(8/9), s_2_9 = Math.sqrt(2/9), s_2_3 = Math.sqrt(2/3);
let v = [
    new THREE.Vector3(0,0,1),
    new THREE.Vector3(s_8_9,0,-1/3),
    new THREE.Vector3(-s_2_9,s_2_3,-1/3),
    new THREE.Vector3(-s_2_9,-s_2_3,-1/3) 
];
```

Use [`THREE.Vector3().lerpVectors`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/math/Vector3.lerpVectors) to compute a point on an edge:

```js
let pointOnEdge = (pt1, pt2, t) => new THREE.Vector3().lerpVectors(pt1, pt2, t);
```

and the inward offset points, of a triangular face:

```js
let computeOffsetPts = (pts, d) => {
    let offsetPts = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < pts.length; ++i) {
        let va = pointOnEdge(pts[i], pts[(i+1) % 3], d);
        let vb = pointOnEdge(pts[i], pts[(i+2) % 3], d); 
        offsetPts.push(new THREE.Vector3().lerpVectors(va, vb, 0.5)); 
    }
    return offsetPts;
}
```

Use this points to construct the mesh. e.g.:

```js
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(60, innerWidth / innerHeight, 1, 100);
camera.position.set(-2, 1, 3);
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(innerWidth, innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

let controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);

const facesColors = [
  0xFFFF00, // yellow
  0xFF0000, // red
  0x0000FF, // blue
  0x008000 // green
]

let s_8_9 = Math.sqrt(8/9), s_2_9 = Math.sqrt(2/9), s_2_3 = Math.sqrt(2/3);
let v = [
    new THREE.Vector3(0,0,1),
    new THREE.Vector3(s_8_9,0,-1/3),
    new THREE.Vector3(-s_2_9,s_2_3,-1/3),
    new THREE.Vector3(-s_2_9,-s_2_3,-1/3) 
];
let faces = [[0, 1, 2], [0, 2, 3], [0, 3, 1], [1, 3, 2]]

let pointOnEdge = (pt1, pt2, t) => new THREE.Vector3().lerpVectors(pt1, pt2, t);

let computeOffsetPts = (pts, d) => {
    let offsetPts = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < pts.length; ++i) {
        let va = pointOnEdge(pts[i], pts[(i+1) % 3], d);
        let vb = pointOnEdge(pts[i], pts[(i+2) % 3], d); 
        offsetPts.push(new THREE.Vector3().lerpVectors(va, vb, 0.5)); 
    }
    return offsetPts;
}

let newTriangle = (pts, color, d) => {
    let innerPts = computeOffsetPts(pts, d);
    let material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: color })
    let geometry = new THREE.Geometry();
    geometry.vertices.push(...innerPts); 
    geometry.faces.push(new THREE.Face3(0, 1, 2));
    return new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
}

const d = 0.05;
for (let i=0; i < 4; ++i ) {
    
    let color = facesColors[i]; 
    let pts = [v[faces[i][0]], v[faces[i][1]], v[faces[i][2]]];
    let centerPt = new THREE.Vector3().addVectors(pts[0], pts[1]).add(pts[2]).divideScalar(3);
    let hexagonPts = [];
    for (let j = 0; j < 3; ++j) {
        hexagonPts.push(pointOnEdge(pts[j], pts[(j+1) % 3], 1/3), pointOnEdge(pts[j], pts[(j+1) % 3], 2/3));
    }
    
    for  (let j = 0; j < 3; ++j) {
        let topPts = [pts[j], hexagonPts[j*2], hexagonPts[(j*2+5)%6]];
        let face = newTriangle(topPts, color, d);
        scene.add(face);
    }
    for (let j = 0; j < hexagonPts.length; ++j) {
        innerPts = [centerPt, hexagonPts[j], hexagonPts[(j+1)%hexagonPts.length]];
        let face = newTriangle(innerPts, color, d);
        scene.add(face);
    }
}

renderer.setAnimationLoop(() => {
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://rawcdn.githack.com/mrdoob/three.js/r113/build/three.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawcdn.githack.com/mrdoob/three.js/r113/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
```

Comment: with i<4 and j<3 and j<3 it creates 24 meshes. If i set the second j<1 it still works and with 16 meshes as this figure should be

Comment: @JeffProd I've improved the answer.