# Rotation animation on another axis

Tags: three.js

I'm trying to rotate objects on a different axis than the default one, and with animation.

Here is actually how i am doing it. You can click on buttons `L` and `Li` that actually work. But as you can see for the `R` button the axis of rotation should be changed. I can't figure how to do this. Am I doing things right about this kind of rotation animation ?

```js
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(60, innerWidth / innerHeight, 1, 100);
camera.position.set(-2, 1, 3);
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(innerWidth, innerHeight - 60); // -60 to see buttons below
const divid = document.getElementById('myid');
divid.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

// show axis
scene.add(new THREE.AxesHelper(2))

let controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);

// one triangle equilateral
const sideLength = 1
const x = 0
const y = 0
const geometry = new THREE.Geometry()
geometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(x, (Math.sqrt(3) / 2 * sideLength) - (sideLength / 2), 0))
geometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(x - (sideLength / 2), y - (sideLength / 2), 0))
geometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(x + (sideLength / 2), y - (sideLength / 2), 0))
geometry.faces.push(new THREE.Face3(0, 1, 2))

const facesColors = [
  0xFFFF00, // yellow
  0xFF0000, // red
  0x0000FF, // blue
  0x008000 // green
]

const pos = [
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3
]

const d = 0.05 // écart entre les triangles
let face
const facesVectors = [
  [0, 1, 2],
  [0, 2, 3],
  [0, 3, 1],
  [1, 3, 2]
]

// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60774560/drawing-a-pyraminx-with-triangles
// coords des points d'un tétrahèdre
const s89 = Math.sqrt(8 / 9)
const s29 = Math.sqrt(2 / 9)
const s23 = Math.sqrt(2 / 3)
const v = [
  new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 1),
  new THREE.Vector3(s89, 0, -1 / 3),
  new THREE.Vector3(-s29, s23, -1 / 3),
  new THREE.Vector3(-s29, -s23, -1 / 3)
]

const computeMidPts = (pts) => {
  const midPts = []
  for (let i = 0; i < pts.length; ++i) {
midPts.push(new THREE.Vector3().lerpVectors(pts[i], pts[(i + 1) % 3], 0.5))
  }
  return midPts
}

const computeInnerPts = (pts, d) => {
  const innerPts = []
  for (let i = 0; i < pts.length; ++i) {
const va = new THREE.Vector3().lerpVectors(pts[i], pts[(i + 1) % 3], d)
const vb = new THREE.Vector3().lerpVectors(pts[i], pts[(i + 2) % 3], d)
innerPts.push(new THREE.Vector3().lerpVectors(va, vb, 0.5))
  }
  return innerPts
}

let allfaces = [];

for (let i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
  const pts = [v[facesVectors[i][0]], v[facesVectors[i][1]], v[facesVectors[i][2]]]

  const outerPts = computeInnerPts(pts, d)
  for (let j = 0; j < 3; ++j) {
const geometry = new THREE.Geometry()
geometry.vertices.push(outerPts[j])
geometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3().lerpVectors(outerPts[j], outerPts[(j + 1) % 3], 0.5 - d / 2))
geometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3().lerpVectors(outerPts[j], outerPts[(j + 2) % 3], 0.5 - d / 2))
geometry.faces.push(new THREE.Face3(0, 1, 2))
const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: facesColors[i] })
face = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material)
allfaces.push(face)
scene.add(face)
  }

  const midPts = computeMidPts(outerPts)
  const innerPts = computeInnerPts(midPts, d / 2)
  const geometry = new THREE.Geometry()
  geometry.vertices.push(...innerPts)
  geometry.faces.push(new THREE.Face3(0, 1, 2))
  const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: facesColors[i] })
  face = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material)
  allfaces.push(face)
  scene.add(face)
}

let movingL = false
let movingLi = false
let movingR = false
let pivot = null
renderer.setAnimationLoop(() => {
  if (movingL) {
pivot.rotation.z += 0.05
if (pivot.rotation.z >= (2 * Math.PI) / 3) {
  movingL = false
}
  } else if (movingLi) {
pivot.rotation.z -= 0.05
if (pivot.rotation.z <= -(2 * Math.PI) / 3) {
  movingLi = false
} 
  } else if (movingR) {
pivot.rotation.x -= 0.05
if (pivot.rotation.x <= -(2 * Math.PI) / 3) {
  movingR = false
} 
  }
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
});

document.getElementById("L").addEventListener("click", function(){
  pivot = new THREE.Group();
  scene.add(pivot);
  
  // faces to move 
  pivot.attach(allfaces[0]);
  pivot.attach(allfaces[4]);
  pivot.attach(allfaces[8]);
  
  movingL = true
});

document.getElementById("Li").addEventListener("click", function(){
  pivot = new THREE.Group();
  scene.add(pivot);
  pivot.attach(allfaces[0]);
  pivot.attach(allfaces[4]);
  pivot.attach(allfaces[8]);  
  movingLi = true
});

document.getElementById("R").addEventListener("click", function(){
  pivot = new THREE.Group();
  scene.add(pivot);
  pivot.attach(allfaces[1]);
  pivot.attach(allfaces[10]);
  pivot.attach(allfaces[12]);  
  movingR = true
});
```

```html
<script src="https://threejs.org/build/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>

<div id="myid"></div>
<button id="L">L</button>
<button id="Li">Li</button>
<button id="R">R</button>
<button id="Ri">Ri</button>
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to have to use [`Quaternions`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/math/Quaternion), which are a much more robust method to apply rotations to objects.

Quaternions have a method called [`.setFromAxisAngle()`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/math/Quaternion.setFromAxisAngle) that you can use to set whatever axis of rotation you want.

In the example below, each time you click a button, I set the axis of rotation and reset the angle of rotation with:

```
axisVector.set(x, y, z).normalize();
quatAngle = 0;
```

(normalize ensures the axis always has [a total length of 1](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/math/Vector3.normalize). Using an axis vector of `(2, 0, 0)` would break the rotation)

Once you have your axis established, you can rotate the pivot with

```
quatAngle += 0.05;
pivot.quaternion.setFromAxisAngle(axisVector, quatAngle);
```

I wasn't exactly sure where the axis of rotation is for `R` or `U`, so I just visually estimated them at `(1, 0, -0.33)` and `(-0.4, 0.7, -0.3)`, then I used `.normalize()` to make its length 1.

```js
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(60, innerWidth / innerHeight, 1, 100);
camera.position.set(-2, 1, 3);
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(innerWidth, innerHeight - 60); // -60 to see buttons below
const divid = document.getElementById('myid');
divid.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

// show axis
scene.add(new THREE.AxesHelper(2))

let controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);

// one triangle equilateral
const sideLength = 1
const x = 0
const y = 0
const geometry = new THREE.Geometry()
geometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(x, (Math.sqrt(3) / 2 * sideLength) - (sideLength / 2), 0))
geometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(x - (sideLength / 2), y - (sideLength / 2), 0))
geometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(x + (sideLength / 2), y - (sideLength / 2), 0))
geometry.faces.push(new THREE.Face3(0, 1, 2))

const facesColors = [
 0xFFFF00, // yellow
 0xFF0000, // red
 0x0000FF, // blue
 0x008000 // green
]

const pos = [
 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3
]

const d = 0.05 // écart entre les triangles
let face
const facesVectors = [
 [0, 1, 2],
 [0, 2, 3],
 [0, 3, 1],
 [1, 3, 2]
]

// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60774560/drawing-a-pyraminx-with-triangles
// coords des points d'un tétrahèdre
const s89 = Math.sqrt(8 / 9)
const s29 = Math.sqrt(2 / 9)
const s23 = Math.sqrt(2 / 3)
const v = [
 new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 1),
 new THREE.Vector3(s89, 0, -1 / 3),
 new THREE.Vector3(-s29, s23, -1 / 3),
 new THREE.Vector3(-s29, -s23, -1 / 3)
]

const computeMidPts = (pts) => {
 const midPts = []
 for (let i = 0; i < pts.length; ++i) {
midPts.push(new THREE.Vector3().lerpVectors(pts[i], pts[(i + 1) % 3], 0.5))
 }
 return midPts
}

const computeInnerPts = (pts, d) => {
 const innerPts = []
 for (let i = 0; i < pts.length; ++i) {
const va = new THREE.Vector3().lerpVectors(pts[i], pts[(i + 1) % 3], d)
const vb = new THREE.Vector3().lerpVectors(pts[i], pts[(i + 2) % 3], d)
innerPts.push(new THREE.Vector3().lerpVectors(va, vb, 0.5))
 }
 return innerPts
}

let allfaces = [];

for (let i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
 const pts = [v[facesVectors[i][0]], v[facesVectors[i][1]], v[facesVectors[i][2]]]

 const outerPts = computeInnerPts(pts, d)
 for (let j = 0; j < 3; ++j) {
const geometry = new THREE.Geometry()
geometry.vertices.push(outerPts[j])
geometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3().lerpVectors(outerPts[j], outerPts[(j + 1) % 3], 0.5 - d / 2))
geometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3().lerpVectors(outerPts[j], outerPts[(j + 2) % 3], 0.5 - d / 2))
geometry.faces.push(new THREE.Face3(0, 1, 2))
const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: facesColors[i] })
face = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material)
allfaces.push(face)
scene.add(face)
 }

 const midPts = computeMidPts(outerPts)
 const innerPts = computeInnerPts(midPts, d / 2)
 const geometry = new THREE.Geometry()
 geometry.vertices.push(...innerPts)
 geometry.faces.push(new THREE.Face3(0, 1, 2))
 const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: facesColors[i] })
 face = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material)
 allfaces.push(face)
 scene.add(face)
}

let movingL = false
let movingLi = false
let movingR = false
let movingU = false
let pivot = null
let quatAngle = 0;
let axisVector = new THREE.Vector3();

renderer.setAnimationLoop(() => {
 if (movingL) {
  quatAngle += 0.05
  pivot.quaternion.setFromAxisAngle(axisVector, quatAngle);
  if (quatAngle >= (2 * Math.PI) / 3) {
   movingL = false
  }
 } else if (movingLi) {
  quatAngle -= 0.05
  pivot.quaternion.setFromAxisAngle(axisVector, quatAngle);
  if (quatAngle <= -(2 * Math.PI) / 3) {
   movingLi = false
  } 
 } else if (movingR) {
  quatAngle -= 0.05
  pivot.quaternion.setFromAxisAngle(axisVector, quatAngle);
  if (quatAngle <= -(2 * Math.PI) / 3) {
   movingR = false
  } 
 } else if (movingU) {
  quatAngle -= 0.05
  pivot.quaternion.setFromAxisAngle(axisVector, quatAngle);
  if (quatAngle <= -(2 * Math.PI) / 3) {
   movingU = false
  } 
 }
 renderer.render(scene, camera);
});

document.getElementById("L").addEventListener("click", function(){
 pivot = new THREE.Group();
 axisVector.set(0, 0, 1);
 quatAngle = 0;
 scene.add(pivot);
 
 // faces to move 
 pivot.attach(allfaces[0]);
 pivot.attach(allfaces[4]);
 pivot.attach(allfaces[8]);
 
 movingL = true
});

document.getElementById("Li").addEventListener("click", function(){
 pivot = new THREE.Group();
 axisVector.set(0, 0, 1);
 quatAngle = 0;
 scene.add(pivot);
 pivot.attach(allfaces[0]);
 pivot.attach(allfaces[4]);
 pivot.attach(allfaces[8]);  
 movingLi = true
});

document.getElementById("R").addEventListener("click", function(){
 pivot = new THREE.Group();
 axisVector.set(1, 0, -0.33).normalize();
 quatAngle = 0;
 scene.add(pivot);
 pivot.attach(allfaces[1]);
 pivot.attach(allfaces[10]);
 pivot.attach(allfaces[12]);  
 movingR = true
});
document.getElementById("U").addEventListener("click", function(){
 pivot = new THREE.Group();
 axisVector.set(-0.4, 0.7, -0.3).normalize();
 quatAngle = 0;
 scene.add(pivot);
 pivot.attach(allfaces[2]);
 pivot.attach(allfaces[5]);
 pivot.attach(allfaces[14]);  
 movingU = true
});
```

```html
<script src="https://threejs.org/build/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>

<div id="myid"></div>
<button id="L">L</button>
<button id="Li">Li</button>
<button id="R">R</button>
<button id="U">U</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for your nice answer. I need to keep track of each face position in the world after moves. I don't have x,y,z in face.matrix.elements (12, 13, 14). Why ? Or is there another way to do ?

Comment: @JeffProd Sorry but that's an entirely different problem altogether.